# Какие есть варианты асинхронной работы с nhibernate?

Tags: c#, async-await, nhibernate

Ковыряюсь с петпроджектом, использую `nhibernate` для хранения данных.

`Nhibernate` из коробки не умеет в асинхронность, а у меня в принципе хватает `async-await`, чтобы он сломался и начал писать на операцию сохранения:

> NHibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a
>   collection with two open sessions    в
>   NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.SetCurrentSession(ISessionImplementor
>   session)    в
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.OnUpdateVisitor.ProcessCollection(Object
>   collection, CollectionType type)    в
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractVisitor.ProcessValue(Object value,
>   IType type)    в
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractVisitor.ProcessValue(Int32 i,
>   Object[] values, IType[] types)    в
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractVisitor.ProcessEntityPropertyValues(Object[]
>   values, IType[] types)    в
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractVisitor.Process(Object obj,
>   IEntityPersister persister)    в
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.PerformUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event, Object entity, IEntityPersister persister)    в
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsDetached(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    в
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultUpdateEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    в
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    в NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent
>   event)    в NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Update(Object obj)    в...

Хибер настроен на `CurrentSessionContext<ThreadLocalSessionContext>()`, т.е. насколько я понимаю - по сессии на поток. [Все варианты](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-current-session) так или иначе мне похоже не помогут, или я не понимаю справку.

Поэтому, вопрос:

Как можно работать с хибером в асинхронном приложении? Синхронизировать вызовы? Отцеплять объекты от сессии и цеплять к нужной в каждом потоке? (Что фактически выбросит весь кеш первого уровня).

Comment: а можете показать код - как в итоге вы сделали, что хотели. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: С пятой версией nhibernate можно просто указать `CurrentSessionContext<AsyncLocalSessionContext>()` и все async-await запросы будут корректно обрабатываться. Более того, в пятой версии nhibernate и сам уже корректно поддерживает асинхронное выполнение запросов в базу.

Comment: @Александр Вологжанинов вопросы задавайте в комментариях. Ответы предназначены именно для ответа на вопрос.

Comment: @Monk, а можно совсем как для новичка :)? Сейчас для открытия сессии использую такой код: ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
     .Database(JetDriverConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(cs =>
  cs.DatabaseFile(DBpath).Provider("Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0")))
  .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<NHibernateHelper>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
            
            .BuildSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
Где тут можно определить контекст?

Comment: Ага, понял. Можно тут: Fluently.Configure().CurrentSessionContext<AsyncLocalSessionContext>() ...

Теперь осталось понять - будет ли такое открытие сессии асинхронным?

Comment: Открытие сессии - синхронное. Асинхронное именно апи работы с базой данных - когда вы через сессию делаете какие то операции с использованием асинхронных методов.

Comment: @Monk, спасибо! Думал, что можно еще и сессию асинхронно открыть для ускорения :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate не имеет и не поддерживает асинхронный API, поэтому:

1. Попробуйте использовать [`AsyncLocalSessionContext`](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-4031). (UPD: в публичной версии пока недоступен, но можно форкнуть исходники и [заимплементить](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/643) самому.)
2. Попробуйте использовать [однопоточный скедулер](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/09/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/), в котором будут работать все синхронные вызовы NHibernate.
3. Смотрите на другие ORM/microORM (тот же Dapper прекрасно поддерживает асинхронность) или [форки](https://github.com/OnurGumus/nhibernate-core) NHibernate, в которых добавлен асинхронный API. Не иметь асинхронного API, если библиотека работает с IO, -- это уже несерьезно в наше время.

Comment: 1 вариант для 5 версии, которая не публичная ещё, я так понимаю. Таки придётся наверно 2 вариант использовать, ибо форки все какие то подозрительные, нет уверенности что они рабочие и протестированные. Попробую и решу, пока непонятно, удобно ли хоть что-то из этих вариантов.

Comment: @Monk можете потом написать отдельным ответом, что получилось.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что `AsyncLocalSessionContext` можно реализовать (скопировать) самому, он однострочный буквально, и будет работать в публичной версии 4+. Так что как с работы приду, проверю обязательно, ибо выглядит самым простым решением.

Comment: @Monk если есть желание, то да, можете форкнуть текущую релизную версию и добавить асинхоронный контекст сами. По номеру задачи в Джире можно найти пулл-реквест на гитхабе.

Comment: Даже форк не нужен, класс `AsyncLocalSessionContext` просто локальный создал и он работает. В целом, вроде нет проблем, сущности начали сохраняться в другом потоке, данные не теряю.

Comment: @Monk круто. Хайбернетовская фабрика, видимо, смотрит среди всех классов, загруженных в домен.

Comment: Да, там есть какой то механизм поиска, если выбран нестандартный контекст, глубоко не лез, заработало - значит хорошо.